# Is DirectSound supported on Mono?

Tags: .net, mono, directsound

I'm writing an application in .NET2.0 (i have to support legacy equipment) that will use DirectSound. There is a possibility that I will need to port the codebase to Mono to run on some Linux equipment. Does anybody have experience of what might happen to references to DirectSound when I attempt this?

Maybe there is a Mono compliant scenario I haven't encountered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DirectSound is not supported. On Linux/Mono, you would usually use GStreamer, see [Banshee](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tree/src/Backends) for an example.